# Backspace key don't works with KeyPress function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox, that only accepts numbers. It works, but the backspace key has no functionality.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int isNumber = 0;
    e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out isNumber);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `"Backspace"` is not an int. If you want to keep backspace functionality (and probably Left, Right, Dot, Comma and Minus too). Check the KeyCode for those too.

Comment: true, so you can check keycodes with this great page [http://keycode.info/](http://keycode.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back ? e.KeyChar.ToString() : "0", out isNumber);
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition to check backspace click or not

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast keys like this and compare.(backspace)

```
if( e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this condition it's working

```
if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
{
}
else
{
       e.Handled = true;
}
```